# Translation of 'sich bei etwas verlieben'?

Tags: translation

How do you translate 'bei' in terms of 'sich verlieben'...

z.B.

> Das ist Musik, bei der man sich sofort verliebt.

Comment: "sich verlieben" has no relevance here. You can also say "bei der man tanzt", "bei der man ausflippt", "bei der einem sich Haare kräuseln", you name it. A preposition which is closely connected to "sich verlieben", however, is "in" as in "sich in etw. / jdn. verlieben".

Comment: But how bei is translated varies depending on the context... My question is basically abou how you translate bei in the context of 'sich verlieben'

Comment: But yes rephrasing the question like that makes it much clearer

Comment: "Dies ist die Musik..." sounds strange, even though it is not wrong. "Das ist Musik..." is more natural German.

Comment: The "bei" in your question and in the examples of Em1 is always the same. The verb does not change the context.

Comment: Well bei, depending on the verb used, can mean 'in terms of', which it clearly doesn't here, so how does bei der Musik tie in with sich verlieben?

Comment: In welche Sprache willst Du es denn übersetzen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*bei* more or less translates to "while" (I cannot think of a 100% translation at the moment, though).

> This is music that makes you fall in love while listening.

(The "falling in love" is not *with the music*, but with someone/something else)

> This is music that goes well with falling in love

(This misses a bit the reason is in the music)

Answer (score 1):

The important part is the "(Das ist) Musik, bei der"* construction, not the verb.

> Das ist Musik, bei der man tanzt

is a relativ clause with preposition, but I am not sure how to translate the construction most accuratly.

It can be translated as

> "*Dance music*", "*Music to which people are dancing"* or "*That is music that makes people dance*"

More examples

> Das ist Musik, bei der man = *That's music that makes people*
>
> - ausflippt = *go crazy*
> - eine Gänsehaut bekommt = *get goose bumbs* (because the music is so emotional)
> - wegrennen möchte  = *want to run away* (because the music is so bad)
> - heulen muss  = *cry* (because the music is so bad)
> - sich sofort verliebt = *fall in love* (because the music is so good/romantic)

The *fall in love* could refer to the music (to fall in love with the music because it is so good) or it could refer to other people (nearby) (to fall in love with someone near because it is so romantic).

Answer (score 0):

In English, we would say

> That's music to fall in love to.

So in this case `bei` translates as `to`. This is unusual: [Leo gives](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=bei&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0) `near, by, with, during, on, at, in,` and `next to` as possible translations for `bei`, and none of these fits your sentence. I suppose you could say

> That's music to fall in love by.

But that would be my second choice.